# Why is Lombok not being pulled in as a dependency in IntelliJ for this Gradle project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, lombok, gradlew

I'm trying to add Lombok as a dependency. It's been downloaded correctly into my `~/.gradle/caches` directory but I can't see it in IntelliJ which is why my annotations aren't compiling.

Can anyone see any issues? I've tried both `io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok` and `net.ltgt.apt` gradle plugins but neither are working as expected but I suspect the issue is separate to that.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE"
        )
    }
}

plugins {
    id "io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok" version "1.7"
    id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.8"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok'
apply plugin: 'net.ltgt.apt'

//build stuff
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

def cucumberVersion = "1.2.4"

jar {
    baseName = 'feeds-api'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom testRuntime
    }
}

task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime
            args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'src/test/groovy', 'src/test/resources']

        }
    }
}

//Ensure the cucumber tests are executed as part of the build. Makes for a very pretty output.
build.dependsOn cucumber

dependencies {
    compile(
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web",
        "org.code-house:jackson:2.7.6",
        "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.10"
    )

    apt "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.10"

    cucumberRuntime files("${jar.archivePath}")

    testCompile(
        "junit:junit:4.12",
        "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.0.111-beta",
        "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3",
        "info.cukes:cucumber-core:$cucumberVersion",
        "info.cukes:cucumber-java:$cucumberVersion",
        "info.cukes:cucumber-junit:$cucumberVersion"
    )
}

springBoot {
    mainClass = 'com.myapp.Application'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.2.1'
}
```

Comment: After searching for hours for the answer I switched back to using Maven and had everything working within 5 minutes.

Ridiculous that it's that difficult to get it working in Gradle. It should have been trivial but IntelliJ just refused to pick it up. Also had issues with mockito being pulled in. All I can think of it's a conflict in versions.